# Camera action crop not working (Android 11)

Tags: android, crop

when I try to upload a picture, the photo cropping process does not start

Logcat:
`[main] - src or des missed, src: content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FPictures%2FScreenshots%2FScreenshot_2022-11-13-19-56-04-778_org.hcg.IF.jpg, des: null`

Full logcat:
https://gist.github.com/nooobas/fdc8d6ebe7c2129d49959b7ec8407b36

The class that launches the crop:

```
public static final String IMAGE_UNSPECIFIED = "image/*";   
public void startPhotoZoom(Uri uri, int resValue) {
   System.out.println(uri);
   Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
   intent.setDataAndType(uri, IMAGE_UNSPECIFIED);
   intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
   intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
   intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
   intent.putExtra("outputX", 90);
   intent.putExtra("outputY", 90);
   intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

   try
   {
      startActivityForResult(intent, resValue);
   }
   catch(Throwable thw){
      //ActivityNotFoundException
   }
}
```

Activity check results:

```
@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      try {
         // photo taker
         onPhotoActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }
      catch( Exception e )
      {
         
      }
   }

   protected void onPhotoActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//        Log.d("onPhotoActivityResult", "resultCode: "+resultCode+",requestCode:"+requestCode);
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         switch (requestCode) {
         case Cocos2dxHandler.TAKE_PICTURE:
            // 设置文件保存路径这里放在跟目录下
            File picture = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/image.jpg");
            startPhotoZoom(Uri.fromFile(picture), Cocos2dxHandler.CLIP_TAKEN_PICTURE);
            break;
         case Cocos2dxHandler.CHOOSE_PICTURE:
            if(data != null){
               //照片的原始资源地址
               Uri originalUri = data.getData();
            Log.d("onPhotoActivityResulted", "Uri: "+originalUri);
               if(originalUri != null){
                  startPhotoZoom(originalUri, Cocos2dxHandler.CLIP_CHOOSED_PICTURE);
               }
            } 
            break;
         case Cocos2dxHandler.CLIP_TAKEN_PICTURE:
         case Cocos2dxHandler.CLIP_CHOOSED_PICTURE:
            if(data != null)
            {
               saveImg(data);
            }
            break;
         case Cocos2dxHandler.CHOOSE_VIDEO:
            if(data != null)
            {
               Log.d("xiaomi", "select success: ");
               saveVideo(data);
            }
            break;
         default:
            break;
         }
      }
   }
```

Full class:
https://gist.github.com/nooobas/f96a1f1cff67c51a4e735d6d2ce470b2

I looked at similar questions on stackoverflow but it didn't solve my problem
Sorry for my English, I use google translate.

Comment: Well `des` is `null`. Now if there is no destination supplied or only a null..

Comment: Further you should tell us which code line causes that error log.